# org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException (Appium + opencv image comparison)

Tags: java, testing, appium

I have tried this example. https://github.com/cloudgrey-io/appiumpro/blob/master/java/src/test/java/Edition098_Visual_Testing_1.java with opencv but it always throws

org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

Anyone resolved this issue?

Comment: that's a selenium error, not an OpenCV error. I don't see ANY indication of OpenCV in that file. error indicates issue way before any visual comparison can take place. complete traceback please. [tour], [ask], [mre]

Comment: Hi! I did a trace but no clue.. The error throws on this line :  SimilarityMatchingResult res = driver.getImagesSimilarity(baselineImg, driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE), opts); no clear info in appium log

Comment: pull the inner call out and up into a temporary variable. figure out which of the two calls fails.

Comment: I have tried it no luck

Comment: I'm also encountering this error. Were you able to resolve it, @AzharudeenMohammed?

Comment: Use this appium --use-plugins=images while starting appium server

Comment: Works perfectly with that command, thank you! Also just to note for anyone else that may encounter this issue using Appium 2.0, you need to install the images plugin before running the above command of starting the server: appium plugin install images